# MySQL query with LIMIT in descending order doesn't works

Tags: mysql

i have a table with id: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, this query:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,5
```

responds correctly: 1,2,3,4,5.

Now I want to go back, so the new query:

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4,5
```

responds: 10,9,8,7,6 instead of: 5,4,3,2,1

Seems that the LIMIT clause works fine only from the first record onwards,
unfortunately the code returns last record position only (4)
how do you go back?

Thanks at all.

Comment: Not getting the same results; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22e42f4b57e64d27865392be8e758eb1

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe you missed something pertinent from the question or over simplified it. AND  What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon MySql v.5.7..the question has a background error, if you have the records A, B, C, D the C record number is the 2th, if you invert their order using the ORDER BY DESC clause the position 2 corresponds to B. To read the table backwards I need a different solution

Comment: You do know that offset starts from 0 not 1? If you do then I'm still unclear what your question is -  does your table have an auto_increment column as well as values a,b,c,d or some other way of ordering the values (such as timestamp)

Comment: @P.Salmon offset start to 0, you can use any table you want eg with only one column ... ID: 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' without auto increment value or timestamp.
I know a position in the table eg the 2nd ('C' record) and I have to read the previous records using a descending sort on ID (the result should be 'C' .. '' B '..' A ')

Comment: Data stored in sql does not have any intrinsic order so unless there is an auto_increment primary key or a timestamp or somethng else then there is no way of establishing that A and B occurred before C

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5,5
```

Output:

```
5,4,3,2,1
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc9976b5c74cce5bcc173e3c46194a24)

Comment: Mmmh. Unfortunately if you add new records id the risult is ever wrong.

Comment: Using your demo I tried this: SELECT tbl.id FROM (SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,10) AS tbl ORDER BY tbl.id DESC LIMIT 5.5 seems to work correctly, it must be tested for several records.